# python relative import fix

Tags: python

I have a folder structure like this:

```
backend/
   stage/
        stage.py
config.py
```

I am trying to import `config.py` into `stage.py` script with a relative import:

```
from ..backend import config
```

The directory which i run from the shell my script is `stage`, and i get this error:

```
(env) PS C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project\backend\stage> & c:/Users/45291029/Documents/evergreen/project/fastapi/env/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/45291029/Documents/evergreen/project/backend/stage/stage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project\backend\stage\stage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..backend import config
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Thought that by using two dots i go up one directory, like unix systems. If it helps I am using VScode IDE and I have this settings.json:

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
```

I also use `python3.9`

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Python from the top directory of your project, in this case `C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project`, since the relative import system can't access beyond where the Python interpreter runs.

That is, you would run it like this (note the current working directory):

```
(env) PS C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project> & fastapi/env/Scripts/python.exe backend/stage/stage.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're running from `stage/`, then the topmost package that Python is aware of is `stage` (the package). When using relative imports, Python inspects the `__package__` magic variable of each module to get its parent package, but for `stage` it will be `None`.

Judging by your relative import, I assume you mean for `config.py` to be inside the `backend/` directory, and that the indentation is just a typo. If that's the case, you just need to change how you invoke your script:

```bash
python -m backend.stage.stage
```

If `config` is suppose to be a sibling of `backend`, then you will need to add a common ancestor for both as well.

Comment: config is inside backend right. i ran as `python -m backend.stage.stage` and got this `C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project\fastapi\env\Scripts\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'backend.stage.stage' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend')`

Comment: @moth what directory did you run it from? `backend/` should be within in the current directory.

Comment: Also, if its still not working, you may have to add a `__init__.py` inside `backend/` and `stage/`, to signify that they are python packages.

Comment: sorry what would be the best place to put config.py so i can easily import from any subdirectory module placed inside the backend parent directory ? that makes things a bit more easier to understand for me

Comment: since this config.py contain only env variables i want to be able to import this file from all subdiretories

Comment: What you have should work.  Lets say `backend/` resides inside `project/`. `project/backend/` contains `config.py`, `stage/`, and `__init__.py`. `project/backend/stage/` contains `stage.py` and `__init__.py`.  From the `project/` directory you run `python -m backend.stage.stage`.

Comment: isn't `__init__.py` only necessary in python 2 ? python 3 every module inside a dir is package right ?

Comment: @moth, yes this is only precautionary- I didn't know which version you were running. Its still best practice though, since some tools expect it to be there

Comment: `(env) PS C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project\backend> python -m backend.stage.stage
C:\Users\45291029\Documents\evergreen\project\fastapi\env\Scripts\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'backend.stage.stage' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend')`

Comment: i have all inits, i am in backend , running python with the import i placed in the question

Comment: @moth you're currently inside `backend/`- I said to run it from the `project/` directory. That's why its not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use something like

```
backend/
   stage/
        stage.py
config/
    config.py
```

and then use

```
export PYTHONPATH=config
```

and then you could import without any relative stuff in multiple modules

```
import config
```